# How to read past events from the blockchain?

Tags: events

I can read events as they happen with:

```
const eventsWatch = myContract.allEvents();
    eventsWatch.watch((err, res) => {
      if (err) return;
      console.log("Event:", res.event, res.args);
    });
```

This even shows the last event after I refresh the page, but I would like a list of all the past events.

Anyone know how to get this?

I've tried changing `watch` to `get` but then i get undefined objects back...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your filter by:

```
const eventsWatch = myContract.allEvents({fromBlock: 0, toBlock: 'latest'});
```